# ajax post with parameter 500 server not found error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

i am calling  asmx service method with ajax first of all i did with parameter ajax give me error of 500 server not found. my parameter name is same as asmx service here is my code with parameter

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var content = contLocation
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'LibraryService.asmx/BooksContent',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'ContLoc':'" + content + "'},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (response) {

                    var data = response.d;

                    alert(data);

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }

            });




        });
```

and it give me

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)
>   error
>   but when i tried without parameter (yes i changed function in asmx make it without parameter and my ajax code data part turns like to this:

```
  data: "{}",
```

in this case my ajax alert me as i required!

i also tried in parameter like this but still same error.

```
 data: "{'ContLoc':'" + Content+ "'}",
```

Comment: Is your web service URL valid and reachable??..Is the data returned too long?

Comment: actually i am working on localhost  and for local for me yes it is reachable

Comment: 500, is an indication of uncaught exception on the server side for your request. Check for errors on server side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ```
> contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
> ```

… so you are claiming that you are sending JSON.

You also said:

> ```
> data: {'ContLoc':'" + content + "'},
> ```

… so you are actually sending URL Form Encoded data (`ContLoc=%22(whatever content is)%22`).

---

1. Determine if the endpoint you are calling expects URL Form Encoded data, JSON, or something else
2. Fix the data so it matches what the endpoint expects
3. Fix the content type so it matches the data you are sending

---

It *sounds* like you should be sending JSON, in which case the code should look like:

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
data: JSON.stringify({ ContLoc : content }),
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a string

```
" + content + "
```

as $ajax data parameter.

Should it be a simple JSON like this

```
data: {ContLoc: content}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the param this way:

```
data: {'ContLoc': content}
```

I hope helps!